# Sublime Text 2 - Auto-indent for brackets and HTML tags

Tags: autocomplete, format, sublimetext2, indentation, auto-indent

(**Note:** In these examples, I will use the pipe symbol "|" to represent the cursor)

In Sublime Text 2, when I type a brace, it automatically adds a matching brace like this:

```
{|}
```

with the cursor in between the two braces. Then when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it automatically adds an extra new line and an indent, resulting in:

```
{
    |
}
```

However, the same indent behavior does **not** happen with brackets and HTML elements. For example, if I type a bracket "[", it does automatically add the matching bracket like:

```
[|]
```

But when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the result is:

```
[
|]
```

It doesn't add an extra line or indent. Similarly, when I type "div.some-class", then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get:

```
<div class="some-class">|</div>
```

But when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get

```
<div class="some-class">
|</div>
```

Not what I want. The only case that is working correctly is with the braces. But in all 3 cases (braces, brackets, html elements), I want an extra line and indent added. So they should all look like:

Braces:

```
{
    |
}
```

Brackets:

```
[
    |
]
```

HTML elements:

```
<div class="some-class">
    |
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Install EMMET Plugin, it will do that plus tons of extra great features especially for writing HTML and CSS. :)

If you haven't already install Package control (for easily installing new packages/plugins), install it using instructions [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

Then you can simply press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and write `Package Control : Instal Package` and find EMMET and install it. Once done restart Sublime Text and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

I've just figured out for myself how to do one of the things on your list.

I've modified the regex that runs when you press the `"enter"` key.

The old regex checked for this `"operand": "\\{$"` and this `"operand": "^\\}"`

I added `or` checks using the pipe `|` to also check for `[` and `(` in the same manner: `"operand": "\\{$|\\[$|\\($"` and `"operand": "^\\}|^\\]|^\\)"`

---

#### Directions

Navigate to **Preferences>Key Bindings - User**

Personally, I keep this file organized by putting short, simple bindings at the top, and larger, block bindings/concerns at the bottom. I consider the following to be a larger block.

Paste this new code in the file:

```
  // Auto-insert line and indent on square bracket and bracket (parenthesis)
  { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$|\\[$|\\($", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}|^\\]|^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ]
  },
  { "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$|\\[$|\\($", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}|^\\]|^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ]
  },
```

---

A few notes:

- My code does this for parenthesis as I said. (Sublime refers to parenthesis as "brackets", distinguished from "square brackets" and "braces".)
- If you don't want this to work on parenthesis, change the first "operand" check to this: `"operand": "\\{$|\\[$"` and the "operand" check on the next line to this: `"operand": "^\\}|^\\]"`
- Last, I'm guessing Sublime parses it correctly either way, but I have a comma `,` at the end of my closing brace, which would assume you've got some more key bindings that follow. If it's the last binding before the closing square bracket at the end of the file, you should remove the comma.

Also, in Sublime Text 3 at least, your questions about the `<div>` indent has been fixed.

Comment: it doesnt work well for braces '()'. The last brace is also indented.

Comment: I had this problem also, but it was actually being caused in a separate file. It wasn't a keybinding, but for me it was in the `JavaScript.tmPreferences` file **I'm almost positive.** It took me a long time to find the problem, and I didn't document it anywhere. I think there was a line similar to `<key>indentBrackets</key><true/>` at the bottom of my file that I deleted.

Comment: Also, note that parenthesis are called `brackets`, not `braces`.

Comment: I think I found it. Open `Default>Indentation Rules.tmPreferences` and you'll see the line at the bottom `<key>indentParens</key><true/>`

Comment: After consulting its [reference hierarchy](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html), I think you should edit your `User>Indentation_Rules.tmPreferences` file.